# Swift files for new class or struct

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift development and wanted to ask a question related to Swift files.

If I am making a project is it a good or general practice to use only one **struct** or **class** in one file? Do you need to create a different .swift file for every new **struct** or **class** ?

Comment: IMO it is better to create a new file for every new class/structure. I would also group all your models, views, extensions and controllers in different folders.

Comment: As a rule, one would generally use separate files. If you have a situation in which you have two different types for which you are tempted to include in a single file, please update your question with a real-world, practical, example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's common to make a new file per type (struct/class/enum) with the file named for the type, but there are exceptions to the rule. If the type definition is small, and closely related to some other type, then it can be easier to read if it's in the same file with the other type definition - that's quite common with enums. Or if the type is nested in an enclosing type, then it's often written inline. But this is a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary. But create a different .swift file for every new struct or class help you more easy to maintain source code when your codebase is large